# Trimming a 3D model

Tags: edit-mode

I have imported a 3D .obj model into Blender for the purpose of trimming off the jagged edges produced by the WebODM software.

Ideally I would like to select a circular region of interest, invert it and then delete everything outside of the circle (or a rectangle instead) but as a new user I can’t see how to do that.

When I select the circular selection tool it doesn’t seem to select anything when I click over the model. Should I be in Body view or Edit mode to trim the model?

Thanks

Comment: hello please show some screenshots of the wireframe, maybe even share your file

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in Edit Mode to select- you can Invert your selection with Crtl+I

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I have tried to cut out the area of the model I'm interested in and it seems a lot of detail inside the circle has also been deleted. I have some screen grabs but I can't see how to add them to this reply?

Comment: I will have to start a new question to see the option of inserting an image - doesn't sound right